# Hypergeometric function relation knowing initial value?

Tags: recurrence-relations, hypergeometric-function

Is there a relationship or recurrence relation I can use to solve for

$$\, _2F_1(b,r+k;a+b+k;p)$$

as a function of $k$, with known value of when $k=0$

$$ \, _2F_1(b,r;a+b;p) = f_0$$

(a,b,r,p) are positive real numbers and k is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the formula 15.5.7 [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.5) (after exchanging $a$ and $b$). That is,
\begin{align}
&_2F_1(a,b+k,c+k,z)=\\=&(-1)^k\frac{(c)_k(1-z)^{1-b-k}}{(c-a)_k(b)_k}\left((1-z)\frac{d}{dz}(1-z)\right)^k (1-z)^{b-1}{}_2F_1(a,b,c,z),
\end{align}
where $(s)_k$ denotes the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html).

Comment: That seems to be exactly what looking for, however I can't seem to verify it. Using exact notation on the page, it seems the first term on LHS reduces to $(1-z)^n*(-1)^n*n!$. Rearranging and solving for $f_n$ yields $f_n=\frac{(1)_n (c)_n}{(a)_n (c-b)_n}f_0$. Testing with random values doesn't seem to match. Did I misinterpret the formula? Thanks!

Comment: It seems another relation is given [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/20/02/05/0006/), however $f_0$ is given and not a function as is shown inside the derivative expression.

Comment: Dear @sheppa28 both identities are actually equivalent. I've checked this numerically, but this can be easily shown using e.g. formula 15.5.10 from the same link. Concerning the mismatch, I would advise to carefully check all powers and parameters in your expression.

Comment: I did use 15.5.10, but I guess did it wrong. I will take a second look. According to this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410057) the recursion is second-order. All I know is the value of f_0 and parameters within 2F1; if I knew f_1 I could continue the recursion.